# Необходимо раскритиковать код и дать советы по исправлению

Tags: c, строки, функции, инспекция-кода

Помогите исправить мой недо-код, пожалуйста. Даны две строки равной длины. Объединить их в одну строку и записать на место первой так, чтобы на нечётных местах шли буквы первой строки, а на чётных - второй.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int output(char* s);
int st_len(char* st);
int main()
{
    char* st1, * st2, * st;
    int i = 0;
    st1 = (char*)calloc(1, 1);
    fgets(st1, 255, stdin);
    output(st1);
    st2 = (char*)calloc(1, 1);
    fgets(st2, 255, stdin);
    output(st2);
    st_len(st1);
    st = 0;
    do
    {   
        st += st1[i];
        st += st2[i];
        i++;
    } 
    while (i<=2*st_len(st1));
    st1 = st;
    output(st1);
}
int output(char* s)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("\n");
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
int st_len(char* st)
{
    int n = 0;
    for (; st[n] != '\0'; n++);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: С выделением памяти очень плохо у вас. Нужных размеров не задаёте. Не выделяете для результата. И не освобождаете. С добавлением буквы у вас всё плохо, вы меняете указатель `st += st1[i];`, а не строку. Цикл `while (i<=2*st_len(st1));` выходит за пределы изначальных строк. Будет крах ошибки памяти. Всё полностью нужно переделывать.

Comment: `calloc(1,1)` выделяет один байт памяти и зануляет его. st_len - не нужен, есть же strlen

Comment: Так то и `output` не особо нужен. А `fgets` оставляет в строке символ новой строки.

Comment: Нет проверки, что строки одинаковой длины. Опять будет всё плохо.

Comment: Люди, вы, по-моему, делаете ошибку - не смотрите на это: *записать на место первой так*... - т.е. если строки abcdef и ghijkl, то вместо первой должно быть ahcjel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массиву букв нужно выделить память по больше. И обнуление не нужно вообще.

```
st1 = (char*)malloc(510);
st2 = (char*)malloc(255);
st  = (char*)malloc(510);
```

Функция `fgets` считывает строку вместе с символом конца строки `\n`. Желательно его убрать, а то будет лишние переносы строк. Проверять надо его наличие потому-что заведённая строка могла быть очень большой.

```
fgets(st1, 255, stdin);
if(st1[strlen(st1)-1] == '\n')
  st1[strlen(st1)-1] = '\00' ;
fgets(st2, 255, stdin);
if(st2[strlen(st2)-1] == '\n')
  st2[strlen(st2)-1] = '\00' ;
```

Проверять надо условие задачи : что строки одинаковой длины. Иначе может быть ошибка доступа к памяти.

```
if(strlen(st1) != strlen(st2)) {
  fputs("String lengths is different\n",stderr);
  goto Exit ; }
```

Циклом заполняем буквы этих строк и команда `+=` изменяет указатель а не строку. Так как строка это массив букв нужно работать как с массивом. Индексы массива длины Length это 0 .. Length-1. И доступ к элементу [Length] будет неправильным. Цикл `i<=2*st_len(st1)` нужно заменить на `i<st_len(st1)`. Попроще можно так :

```
size_t sl = strlen(st1); 
while ( i < sl )
{   
    st [i * 2] = st1[i];
    st [i * 2 + 1] = st2[i];      
    ++ i ;
} 
st [i * 2] = '\00' ;
```

После копирования букв в конце нужно добавить нулевой символ, так как функция печати ориентируется именно на него.

После создания результата нужно строку `st` записать в первую строку `st1` как было сказано в задаче. Ваше присвоение `st=st1;` это присвоение указателя, а не строки. Копировать можно циклом :

```
for(int j=i * 2;j>=0;--j)
  st1[j] = st[j];
```

*Или если кто-то неправильно понял задачу, то так :*

```
size_t sl = strlen(st1); 
while ( i < sl )
{   
    if ( i % 2 == 0 )
      st [i] = st1[i];
    else
      st [i] = st2[i];      
    ++ i ;
} 
st [i] = '\00' ;
for(int j=i;j>=0;--j)
  st1[j] = st[j];
```

Освобождать память нужно всегда, чтобы не забывать. Забывание приведёт к утечке памяти.

```
Exit :
 free(st);
 free(st2);
 free(st1);
```

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, вы делаете ошибку - не смо'трите на это: *записать на место первой так...* - т.е. если строки `abcdef` и `ghijkl`, то вместо первой должно быть `ahcjel`... Далее, я не вижу условия, что нельзя выводить строку как строку или что нельзя использовать ту же `strlen()`.

Поэтому - я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
#define len 300
    char st1[len], st2[len];
    printf("1st string: ");
    fgets(st1, len, stdin);
    printf("2nd string: ");
    fgets(st2, len, stdin);
    if (strlen(st1) != strlen(st2))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"strlen(st1) != strlen(st2)\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("\n\n1st string: %s",st1);
    printf("2nd string: %s",st2);
    
    for(int i = 1; i < strlen(st2); i+=2)
        st1[i] = st2[i];
    printf("Res string: %s",st1);
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/Icjqbt

Comment: Тут условие задачи расплывчато. Русский язык великая вещь. Я сделал как попросили.